# How to stop IntelliJ from reformatting timestamps in SQL query?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, intellij-idea, pycharm

When executing a sql query against an IntelliJ or PyCharm data source using the database console, any timestamps in the results are reformatted to have their time zone offsets stripped out. So they appear like `2016-05-07 06:28:41.672424` instead of like `2016-05-07 12:52:55.504 -0700`.

I don't see this problem if I connect using psql or call the JDBC driver from Java.

Is there a way to control how IntelliJ / PyCharm format timestamps in query results?

Comment: Also contributing to my suspicion that this is an IDE issue, when I run `select current_timestamp;` in pycharm, the header in the results is `now(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff)`. I don't think that is coming from the db.

Comment: That is because it uses JDBC, and likely uses the normal `getTimestamp` method, which doesn't have a concept of timezones.